# spring boot repackage with proguard

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

is there any way to obfuscate jar in boorRepackaged in gradle?

I got proguard task between jar task and bootRepackage task, but failed to make bootRepackage task take the obfuscated-jar which is generated from proguard task.